# Error in cluster_edge_betweenness

Tags: r, igraph

I am using the function `cluster_edge_betweenness` provided in iGraph, but I run into error `Modularity is implemented for undirected graphs only.`

```
g <- read.csv("sample.csv", header = FALSE) 
G <- graph.data.frame(g)
cluster_edge_betweenness(G)

head(g)
> `   V3       V5
   1 614      644
   2 614     3960
   3 614     4156
   4 614     9902
   5 614    11487
   6 614 68400038`
```

Above are the first few lines of my data. Any advice on how to solve this issue?

Comment: Is your graph undirected or directed? If the former, the former, set `directed=FALSE` in `graph.data.frame()`; if the latter, give some sort of reference to the definition of betweeness you want to use for directed graphs because igraph doesn't have one built in.

Comment: Thanks, that solves the problem

Comment: @MrFlick when you say to "give some sort of reference to the definition of betweenness you want to use for directed graphs", how does one go about this exactly? I have been trying to get this function to work for directed graphs, but I keep running into "Modularity is implemented for undirected graphs only."