# R and iGraph: Modularity is Implemented for Undirected Graphs Only

Tags: r, igraph

I am attempting to use the `cluster_edge_betweenness` function in iGraph. It works perfectly for undirected graph objects, but I am getting the `Modularity is implemented for undirected graphs only` error when attempting to use this function on directed graph objects.

I have found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51792302/error-in-cluster-edge-betweenness), but it does not completely resolve my issue. They suggest that I...

> give some sort of reference to the definition of betweenness you want
>   to use for directed graphs

However, I cannot figure out how to do this. May somebody please point me in the correct direction?

EDIT: The following is a reproducible example of my issue.

1. I produce a graph object for the function. It appears as follows:

```
IGRAPH 7ddde0d DNW- 4 11 -- 
+ attr: name (v/c), weight (e/n)
+ edges from 7ddde0d (vertex names):
 [1] 2->3 2->1 2->4 3->2 3->1 3->4 1->2 1->3 1->4 4->2 4->3
```

2. I assign this graph object to a variable. Let's call that `G` for now.
3. I run the function with the following parameters:

```
suppressWarnings(igraph::cluster_edge_betweenness(graph = G, directed = TRUE))
```

4. I get the following result:

```
Modularity is implemented for undirected graphs only.
Modularity is implemented for undirected graphs only.
Modularity is implemented for undirected graphs only.
Modularity is implemented for undirected graphs only.
$g_sub
IGRAPH clustering edge betweenness, groups: 1, mod: 0
+ groups:
  $`1`
  [1] "2" "3" "1" "4"
```

NOTE: The result is the exact same as an undirected graph run with the same **directed** graph object (i.e. if I were to run the Step 3 code with `directed = FALSE` instead, with everything else constant). The only difference is that I get `Modularity is implemented for undirected graphs only` printed multiple times before the result.

Comment: Could you add a reproducible example?

Comment: @JamesMartherus I have added a code example of events leading up to my error. Please let me know if I can help clarify anything. Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you using the most recent version of the `igraph` package?  I get no such warning.

Comment: @G5W R igraph version 1.2.4.1 is loaded via a namespace but not attached. Could this affect the outcome?